# My ELSE condition refuses to run in IF/ELSE Laravel

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-8

I have a basic if/else statement is Laravel.

```php
$model = MyModel::where('row', 'abc123')->first();

// Returns 3 statuses - connected, inactive, disconnected
$status = getStatus();

if ($status === 'connected') {
   if (!$model->is_active) {
       $model->timed_at = now();
   }

   $model->is_active = true;
}
else {
   if ($model->is_active) {
       $model->last_timed_at = $model->updated_at;
   }

   $model->is_active = false;
}

$model->save();
```

**NOTE:** This function is called repeatedly at an interval of 10 seconds.

The ELSE functionality works flawlessly outside the ELSE statement.

But the moment it's in the ELSE, it doesn't run at all.
I have proven that it does reach the ELSE by adding an `echo` which works fine.

Another odd thing, when I place the ELSE in the IF side, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think there is much we can help with here without seeing the code you aren't sharing. There is nothing about an `if/else` that would cause the behavior you are seeing. The one question I can think to ask, though, is: What do you mean "refuses to work". How did you determine that it refuses to work? Does it throw an error, do something you didn't intend? Do nothing at all?

Comment: Based on the minimal information you're willing to share, I'd presume "something else" uses `$var` in some fashion, and that a particular value is giving it trouble... or that you've just got a mistake in "something else" in general.

Comment: @JNevill Here's some extra information I missed out actually, it keeps running the IF part, even if `$var` doesn't satisfy the condition. But when I add an `echo` in the ELSE part as a test, it runs accordingly. Very odd.

Comment: @ceejayoz Apologies for the minimal information, cannot share code unfortunately. But to answer your question, the ELSE part doesn't make use of `$var`

Comment: That only deepens the mystery. Is this `if/else` inside of a loop that maybe you aren't thinking through? Is this else portion in this loop setting a variable that you are inspecting after the loop is ran but it only ever has the `if` value for that variable and never the `else` version of that variable (because each iteration of the loop is overwriting the previous iterations setting)? I ask because that is a VERY common mistake/question people ask on here. As it stands we can only guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: For next steps, it would make sense to write some code that exhibits the same issues that you can share here. Without that, there really isn't anything we can do besides guess.

Comment: @JNevill I will edit my question to somewhat match my work code.

Comment: @JNevill I have made some edits. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: @JNevill I've just spotted my mistake. It was an issue with the way I was testing it.

Comment: `if/else` statements don't break for no reason. You may think that the condition isn't matched, but you must be wrong.

Comment: Oh good! I'm so glad you found it. It was really shaping up to be a "How did you determine it was broken" type of question since there is nothing that could cause the behavior you were seeing in the code you provided. So happy to hear that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input.
Turns out the data I was tweaking during my testing gave me unexpected (they were actually expected) results.

Not sure how to fully close a question, but leaving this here to say it was a non-issue.